# before_action hook in case of Ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Some of my controllers have `before_action` hooks in order to make sure that the model instance belong to the right user, or that a user is authenticated

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :check_owner

private

def check_owner
  Unless current_user.id == Myobject.find(params[:id]).user.id
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Now I am wondering if I do an Ajax request (`remote: true` argument to a form) would the `before_action` hooks pass in case no User is authenticated for example ? At least I guess the redirections would fail..

If the hooks do the job, then I am happy. But maybe there is a better way to do this or get the redirections work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `before_action` would still halt the request in the case of `remote: true`, however as you mentioned, the redirect as you have it above will only work for requests with HTML format. The best way to handle the redirect for a JS request is by adding your own method in `ApplicationController` to handle all desired request formats:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def all_formats_redirect_to(path)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to path }
      format.js { render js: "window.location = #{path.to_json}" }
      # you can add how you want to handle redirect for other formats if you use them
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

And then instead of using `redirect_to` in your `before_action`s (or even in actions that handle multiple formats), you can use `all_formats_redirect_to`:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :check_owner

private

def check_owner
  unless current_user.id == Myobject.find(params[:id).user_id
    all_formats_redirect_to(root_path)
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is definitely a very good idea to handle this globally.